# getComputedStyle local vs every time in function Performance

Tags: javascript

Which is better performance wise if I need to take the ComputedStyle of an element many times on different places in my code. Is it better or worse to make the ComputedStyle a global variable?

Also is a global variable better for performance in a case where the element is moved a lot, but I don't need the computed style on every move, but only when special event is fired would in this case the computed style in the global variable be recalculated without me needing it?

Or does the calculation begin only if I try to take a value from the coumputed style variable?

Will this also be the case when using getBoundingClientRect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle), it's a *live* object, and so it will get the property as of when you ask for the property, not as of when you get the object.

We can verify that experimentally as well:

```js
var example = document.getElementById("example");
var style = getComputedStyle(example);
console.log("A: color = " + style.color);
example.className = "green";
console.log("B: color = " + style.color);
```

```css
.green {
    color: green;
 }
```

```html
<div id="example">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

That outputs:

```
A: color = rgb(0, 0, 0)
B: color = rgb(0, 128, 0)
```

on Chrome, Firefox, IE11, and Edge. Note how adding the class changed the property value.

That being the case, I suspect `getComputedStyle` is **really** fast and it doesn't make a lot of difference whether you keep the object or repeat the call to get it. But as always, when performance is critical (is it really critical in this case?), test the performance of your **actual** code.

---

> Is it better or worse to make the ComputedStyle a global variable?

I strongly recommend avoiding actual **global** variables as much as possible. On browsers, the global namespace is **really** crowded and it's easy to run into conflicts. (For instance: You can't have a global called `name` and assign anything to it other than a string, because it conflicts with the `window.name` property, which is the name of the window, and is always a string.) It's very nearly possible to completely avoid them. But you can have variables that are global *to your code* if you need them. For instance, in the following, `example` is global to the code in the example, but not an actual global variable:

```js
// Scoping function
(function() {
    // `example` is "global" to this code
    var example = 21;
    
    function foo() {
        console.log(example);
    }

    
    function bar() {
        example *= 2;
    }
    
    bar();
    foo();
})();
```

A more modern way is to use *modules*. True JavaScript modules work in modern web browsers, and you can use bundlers like Webpack or Rollup to handle creating bundles for older browsers.

Comment: Yes, what I meant global in my code was the closure in which I am using the variable. Is closure considered a module in any way?

Comment: @heyza22 - Not really, though older module systems (CommonJS for instance) did use closures (which is to say, functions) to wrap all code in a module so that the module didn't create globals. But a closure does provide a scope for variables to be common to just your code.